# CLGeocoder returning different placemarks on iOS 5.1 and 6.0 simulators

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, geocoding, core-location, clgeocoder

I'm using `CLGeocoder` method `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` in order to obtain placemarks.

Testing it with a string like *Avinguda de Madrid 100*, I get:

- 3 results in 6.0 simulator
- 1 result in 5.1 simulator

This happens both on iPhone and iPad simulators.

I thought my code was wrong, but Apple's [Geocoder Demo project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) has this issue too, as you can see in the two screenshots below (note the dots pointing to a result that is shown on both screenshots):

[image] [image]

If you want to reproduce  it on Apple's sample code,

- Select the *Forward* tab (it opens by default).
- Enter *Avinguda de Madrid 100* in the text field.
- Tap on the *Geocode String* button (without enabling *Include Hint Region*).

Have you had this issue before? Am I missing anything? Or should I move to Google Places API?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 6 SDK supports both iOS5 and iOS6. MapKit work with Googles APIs on iOS5 and with their own Apple APIs on iOS6. (The dependency is on the system version, not the SDK version.)

I guess, `CLGeocoder` of the iOS 6 SDK uses Google APIs in the 5.1 Simulator and Apple APIs in the 6.0 Simulator. Thus I would expect different results.

If `CLGeocoder` uses Apples services in both cases, I still would expect differences due to the changes stated above.